# Can I select the rows that have the greatest Column A values compared to all other rows which have identical columns B in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

Perhaps not the clearest explanation.

I have this table:

```
+-----+------+
| ID  | Time |
+-----+------+
|  1  |  5   |
|  1  |  2   |
|  1  |  4   |
|  2  |  1   |
|  2  |  5   |
|  3  |  6   |
+-----+------+
```

I want the row with ID=1 that has the greatest Time *compared to other rows where ID=1*.  The same with WHERE ID=2, etc.  So essentially "get me all the rows that have greatest Time as compared to other rows that have the same ID as them".  So the results in this case would be:

```
+-----+------+
| ID  | Time |
+-----+------+
|  1  |  5   |
|  2  |  5   |
|  3  |  6   |
+-----+------+
```

Comment: **Never** use SQL keywords as variable names - it causes all sorts of problems! p.s. welcome to the forum!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT id, MAX(`time`) AS `time`
FROM sourcetable
GROUP BY id;
```

PS. Stop thinking in iterations, think in datasets.

Comment: Thanks, this worked.  What do you mean by not thinking in iterations?

Comment: @DuncanMarshall *... the row with ID=1 ... The same with WHERE ID=2, etc.* - this is iterational thinking type. Its negative effect will be visible when you'll study correlated subqueries and rowset-used checking expressions.

Comment: I didn't mean that I wanted to iterate over the database, I wanted it in one query.  It was just a way of being clear in the question.

Comment: A slight problem with this.  It only returns the columns id and time, whereas I was expecting all of them, as though I'd done SELECT *.  Is there any fixing this?

Comment: @DuncanMarshall Use this query as a subquery, and get the whole rows using obtained values as a filtering conditions from another copy of source table.

Comment: What would the syntax for that be?